# How to instantiate a variable in Nuxt

Tags: html, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I've tried a couple of different ways to instantiate a variable in Nuxt but neither way seems to work. I have read around the subject and suspect that perhaps what I'm trying to do is not compatible with Webpack but I'm not sure how.

Here is a jsFiddle of the code: [jsfiddle.net/tutmoses/z2365g49/4](https://jsfiddle.net/tutmoses/z2365g49/4)

First in the script section I export `dataSize`:

```
<script>
export default {
   data(){
      return {
         page_name: "Run Model",
         dataSize: 1296

      }
   }
</script>
```

Then in the HTML above I'm trying to import it but nothing renders:

```
<div class="setting">
  <span class="setting-label">Training Size:</span>
  <input id="trainingSize" :value="dataSize"></input>
</div>
```

I've also tried this:

```
<div class="setting">
  <span class="setting-label">Training Size:</span>
  <input id="trainingSize" :value= {{ dataSize }}></input>
</div>
```

...but the value instantiates as

> {{

I've tried both of the above options without binding the `value` but that didn't work either.

Another way I've tried is this in a separate file:

```
export const nnSettings = {
  dataSize: 1296
}
```

And then importing it with this:

```
import nnSettings from '~/components/testindex.js'
```

Again, zip.

The reason why I'm importing the value is because other values will be calculated from it. What would be the standard, best way to do it?

Comment: It hasn't solved the problem but I don't think that's because your answer is wrong. There's something else in the code I think that is causing the problem so I'm trying to work it out. Unfortunately that means I can't verify that you've solved it. Strangely, nothing is appearing in the form box at all. It's a mystery at the moment...

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt (Vue) uses `v-model` to bind to form input. Have a look [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) for more info on form bindings

```
<div class="setting">
  <span class="setting-label">Training Size:</span>
  <input id="trainingSize" v-model="dataSize"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/tutmoses/z2365g49/4/ I wonder if it needs a "value" but the literature seems to suggest that v-model replaces "value" as well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JackPutter is that *all* you have? the example is not a vue project at all. It is just html and a javascript file and they are not linked in anyway. I strongly suggest you look at this https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_vue.asp quick start intro on vue. Also go to the official vue website https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ go through it carefully. 

Once you are familiar with vue then look at Nuxt website https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation.